# TypeError: get_user_id() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Tags: load-testing, locust

I am getting following error

***TypeError: get_user_id() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'***

**my code**

from locust import HttpUser

class AbstractUser(HttpUser):
abstract = True

```
def __init__(self, parent):
    super(AbstractUser, self).__init__(parent)
    self.user_attr = {}


def set_token(self, token):
    self.user_attr['token'] = token

def get_token(self):
    if 'token' in self.user_attr.keys():
        return self.user_attr['token']
    else:
        return None
```

print(AbstractUser.get_token())

**Error Screenshots**
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not showing the code where the issue is happening. Your error is on line 30 but you don't have 30 lines here. And your error is in calling `get_user_id()` which you don't show defined.

However, if your code where you're seeing this issue is similar to your last line `print(AbstractUser.get_token())` then your use would be that you're trying to call a class method without first creating an instance of the class.

You should do a web search for how to call class methods. This was one of the first results I found that seemed appropriate. I can't fully vouch for the site or its content, but this is the sort of thing you'd be looking for.

https://www.pythontutorial.net/python-oop/python-class-methods/

Comment: Hi @Solowalker, Thanks !
when used regular class and methods its working fine but, when I inherit HttpUser from Locust class, it gives this error.

Comment: In your screenshots, you're still not instantiating the class so the answer is the same. You need to instantiate the class first before you can call its methods. You'd have to do something like `token_instance = AbstractUser()` before you could call `token_instance.get_cookie()`. You may have arguments to pass into `AbstractUser` to instantiate it, though.